# I am facing an issue in attaching a login functionality using firebase in my Disney+ clone project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

The issue is that in import statement

```
import {auth, provider} from "./firebase";
```

the `./firebase` is not recognized by the compiler.

```
ERROR: -
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase' in 'C:\Users\DELL10\Desktop\MYPROJ\disney\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/Header.js 5:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase' in 'C:\Users\DELL10\Desktop\MYPROJ\disney\src\components'

webpack compiled with 1 error.
```

I had tried

1. `npm install firebase`,
2. `npm install firebase-tools`,

and then `yarn start` but it's not working.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {auth, provider} from "../firebase";
const Header = (props) =>{
  const handleAuth = () => {
    auth.SignInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
    })
  };
```

Comment: use correct filepath for the firebase file import, also are you using npm or yarn?

Comment: Do you have a file in the same directory called “firebase.js”/etc? Or do you mean `import xxx from ‘firebase’` *(or `require`)*?

Comment: I am using yarn.

Comment: yes I do have the file "firebase.js" in the src directory

Comment: You should edit the question to show the complete code of all relevant files that is causing this problem, including how they are organized.  We should be able to take what you show and reproduce the problem for ourselves.

Comment: I had updated the header.js file content in the description

Comment: The import looks for the file one directory above; your post implies it’s two directories above.